# Persistent Android deployment from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, deployment

Using Eclipse, I have an Android connected, and I can deploy apps no problem. The apps, however, don't persist. That is, once I exit them, I see no way to start them again (an icon doesn't appear). Is there an easy way to make them persist? (e.g. some flag or something?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having never touched an Android before, total newb moment: apparently the list of icons on the home screen is not a comprehensive list of programs; I found a list button with a grid image, and that brought up a list of all programs. Forgive my incompetence!